# Scroll I Added To My Project Works On Computer But Not On Tablet

Tags: html, css, angular

the scroll feature I added to my project in my Angular project works smoothly when I try it from my computer, but when I switch to the tablet, it does not scroll, what is the reason for this?

My Html Code;

```
 <div class="col-md-12" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; max-height:750px;">
        <table class="table table-bordered istenilenTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th  class="istenlenTh stickyth min-with100"  style="left: -1px; min-width:200px !important; z-index: 1;">{{'measurmentPoint' | translate}}</th>
                    <th class="istenlenTh stickyth min-with100"  style="left: 200px; z-index: 1;">{{'Value' | translate}}</th>
                    <th *ngFor="let realMeasurmentTableDetail of getOrderedMeasurmentTableDetail();let j = index">
                        {{realMeasurmentTableDetail?.sizeName + ' -' + realMeasurmentTableDetail?.bPantNo}}
                        <button class="btn btn-icon deleteBtn"
                            (click)="deleteColumn(realMeasurmentTableDetail.pantNo,realMeasurmentTableDetail.sizeId)">
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </button>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="width: 100%;">
                <tr [ngClass]="{'selected-row': rowIndex === selectedRowIndex}"
                    *ngFor="let measurementPoint of checkedMeasurmentPointId;index as rowIndex">
                    <td  class="istenlenTd stickytd1">
                        {{getMeasurementPoint(measurementPoint)}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="measurement-table-cell istenlenTd stickytd2">
                        {{getMeasurementTableValue(measurementPoint)}}
                    </td>
                    <td id="value"
                        [ngClass]="{'selected-cell': selectedRowIndex === rowIndex && selectedColumnIndex === columnIndex}"
                        *ngFor="let currRealMeasurementTableDetail of getOrderedMeasurmentTableDetailById(measurementPoint);let columnIndex = index;"
                        (click)="setClickIndex(rowIndex,columnIndex,currRealMeasurementTableDetail)">
                        {{currRealMeasurementTableDetail.value}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Web Application Image
: [image: Web Application Image]

Answer (score 0):

probably due to give fixed value like px; it couldnt be responsive , so you couldnt see on the tablet

Comment: reorganized all the data with rem but unfortunately it didn't work again

Comment: This answer looks like it couldbe better suited as a comment - consider adding it to the original post.